# JFrame Layout issue, Panels should be at the top but are in middle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I have two JPanel's that i was to be in the top left corner but for some reason they are half way down the y axis (but still left, so 0 in x axis). I'll post my code here anyway, i think its easier to understand my problem then. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 JFrame scrabbleBoard = new JFrame();                              
    scrabbleBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     

    Container topPane = scrabbleBoard.getContentPane();               
    topPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));   

    JButton done = new JButton ("Done");                              
    JLabel player1 = new JLabel ("Player 1");

    topPane.add(player1);        
    topPane.add(done);        

    scrabbleBoard.pack();
    scrabbleBoard.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
done.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
player1.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
```

See: [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment)

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it properly. What i want is for the two panels to literally be like this "PANEL1 PANEL2" as apposed to on top of each other as they are if i use Y_AXIS... does that make sense?

Comment: @Dave Did you try Reimueus suggestion?